# Using data table I want to search with only first letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I have a table with Owner names. The users wants to be able to sort the tables from first letter on wards.

Example:

1)Saurabh Gujarani
2)Testsa

By searching "Sa" should only list - Saurabh Gujarani

But in my current code it display both.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#custom_2').dataTable({
       "aoColumnDefs": [
  { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [ 0,1,4,5,6,7,8 ] }
] } );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can modify the default search functionality of DataTable as follows.

```
//Declare table
var table = $('Table Selector').DataTable();

//on search box keyup
$('input[type = search]').on( 'keyup', function () {

    //start check from first character
   table.search( '^' + this.value, true, false).draw();
});
```

Please see the working demo https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/b577yxa3/1/

Comment: This code is so helpul i have made changes in my code i have add this code using your ref code
    {
        var oTable = $('#custom_2').dataTable();
        $('input[type = text]').on( 'keyup', function () {
            var ap = $(this).val();
           oTable.fnFilter( "^"+ap, null, true,true,false ).draw();;
       } );
    }
link : http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnFilter

Comment: I add code same like fiddle but it's not working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this to make users able to search for elements in a periodic table.

```js
var searchString = document.getElementById("search").value; //The user input field
    if (searchString !== "") {
    var cols = document.querySelectorAll('#yourTableID td'), colslen = cols.length, i = -1;
 while(++i < colslen){
        if(cols[i].id.indexOf(searchString)>-1){
            //Do something to the tds that match the searchstring (acces with "cols[i]")
        } else {
           //Hide the tds that does not match the searchstring (eg. cols[i].style.display = "none";)
```

I matches the search string with the id of a `<td>`, but I think you might be able to replace the .id. in the if statement, with innerHTML or value if you want to search for the text inside the td.

Hope this helps!